# Why I have a dual boot menu at start-up?

Tags: dual-boot

I have to format and re-installed all the Ubuntu Studio 15.10 OS into my main desktop PC.

Everything is fine, here, now.

The only "rare" thing I have is... A dual-boot menu at start-up!

Rare, because I have only one OS in this PC, so... Why is this?

How can I fix it? Can I?

Greetings & Blessings from Chile!

Juan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a "dual boot" menu, it's the GRUB menu. Normal. If you really want to hide it, run, in a terminal:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Put a # in front of every line that begins with `GRUB_HIDDEN` (there should be two of them) and do the same with `GRUB_DEFAULT`. Now change the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` so it looks like this:

`GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`

Hit Ctrl+O then Enter to save and Ctrl+X to exit. In the terminal, run

`sudo update-grub`

And GRUB menu should be hidden from now on.

Comment: BTW: In that Grub Menu, there is an option (the last option) that says: MS-DOS 5.x. But, I don't have any MS-DOS version installed on this PC. Why is this? ???